# Trimming my CV; or, what is appropriate to have in a CV at a given career stage

Tags: cv

I've been more or less adding material to my CV since I started it while in grad school.  As I am now a much more senior person, I am starting to feel it is a bit cluttered and perhaps larded up with inane facts about my (academic) life.  For instance does it really make sense to continue to include a prize I won as an undergraduate fifteen years ago?  Did it ever?

I'm curious what people think is an appropriate amount of information to include at each career stage: PhD student, Post-doc, Tenure-track, Tenured or if it doesn't make a difference.

I'm in math if people think the subject area matters.

Comment: I keep everything on my CV and then trim it down before sending it off to someplace. Funders, hiring committees, and tenure/promotion committees are all looking for different things.

Answer (score 3):

As has been suggested above, keep one version of your CV which is complete with everything you've ever done, and then trim it down as needed for a particular purpose.  I keep my CV up-to-date with lists of publications, conference presentations, grants, courses taught, graduate students supervised, committees served on, etc.  It's a very long document, but its easy to cut/paste what I need in various situations.

Answer (score 0):

You'll rarely be faulted for having too much in you CV, awards included. Very senior academics will sometimes trim off things that's seem inconsequential in retrospect, but the cutoff is often undergrad (i.e., graduate school accomplishments, however small, are often included). Sometimes even these are omitted, but it's not necessary. It's your record of accomplishments -- be proud.

Comment: Depends on the context. Sometimes a shorter CV is better, because it conveys your point more quickly (that you are good). Full professors usually have a "full CV" that is several pages long. The people I've seen usually send a short tailored CV unless a full is asked.

Comment: Sure, there's a place for a full and abridged.  I was assuming the 'full' version.

Comment: Yes, but that is kind of the point. "CV" defaults to full CV for "entry level" scholars, but usually to short version for more experienced ones. But where are the lines ? (that's the OP question in my view)